# using switch case, error on the default part

Tags: c, case, switch-statement

although default part mustn't run,
 it runs al case, I thanks for all helps at now, what should i do? This code all runs i writes on screen default case.

```
do
{
scanf("%c",&choice);

switch(choice)
{
    case 'T':
        printf("Enter edges of Triangle1\n");
        scanf("%d%d",&edge1,&edge2);
        Triangle1(edge1,edge2);
        break;
    case 't':
        printf("Enter edges of Triangle1\n");
        scanf("%d%d",&edge1,&edge2);
        Triangle2(edge1,edge2);
        break;
    case 'R':
        printf("Enter edges of square\n");
        scanf("%d%d",&edge1,&edge2);
        Rectangle(edge1,edge2);
        break;
    case 'S':
        printf("Enter one edge of square\n");
        scanf("%d",&edge);
        Square(edge);
        break;
    case 'C':
        printf("Enter radius of circile\n");
        scanf("%d",&radius);
        Circle(radius);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Wrong input\n");
        break;
}//end of switch
printf("\n");
}while(choice!='e');
```

Comment: It's likely the `\n` left in the buffer by `%d`.

Comment: Expected inputs may be "T,t,S,R,C"

Comment: They meant asking, what are you entering as input? Also can you `printf` the value that you read using `scanf` most likely it will be `\n`.

Comment: I asked that user enter whatever, program runs default line. when the user enter Wront input, in this time default line should run. I want this. what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

The newline gets passed as well as input. Try calling "getc(stdin)" after the first scanf() and it should work :)

Check out for example: http://home.datacomm.ch/t_wolf/tw/c/getting_input.html#newline